# ordering function seq() in R with the order of input value

Tags: r

My apologize for my bad english i'm a student from france.
I have a little problem with a function in R, indeed i have a dataframe like that :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mrOH.jpg

With this code :

```
testtransect2$TOTAL<-testtransect2$TOTAL*-1
plot(testtransect2$DECA,testtransect2$TOTAL,asp = 1)
xl <- seq(min(testtransect2$DECA),max(testtransect2$DECA), (max(testtransect2$DECA)-min(testtransect2$DECA))/1000)
lines(xl, predict(loess(testtransect2$TOTAL~testtransect2$DECA,span = 0.25), newdata=xl))
```

I want to create a plot with a smooth line which pass through all the point in the order of the dataframe  but when i want put my line with my  value xl and predict my plot is not like i want :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbFTH.jpg

I link you a plot where you can see what i want :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbJw0.jpg

i think it's a problem of order in my xl value but i can't do it, if you have any solution
Thanks for give it to me

Comment: Shouldn't be `newdata=xl` in the `predict` call? Can't see `x` defined. Also, specify what's wrong with the plot you got, it's unclear to me. Also, what is `prof`?

Comment: thanks for you answer indeed i past a wrong code i have correct then

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ggplot`

Storing your `dataframe` in `df`

```
df <- data.frame(DECA=c(0,10,15,-23,15,40,90,140,190,250,310,370,420),
                 TOTAL=c(0,-9,-15,-31.5,-48,-50,-44,-24,-17,-10,-6,-5,0))
```

You are interested in `geom_point` and `geom_line`. You can specify `df$DECA` and `df$TOTAL` in `aes` like this:

```
library(ggplot)
ggplot(df, aes(x=DECA, y=TOTAL)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Yielding

[image]

The "but when i want put my line with my value xl and predict my plot is not like i want" part is unfortunately unclear to me, please rephrase if this solution does not work for you.

**Updated**

There are other `smooth_lines` that may be added, eg. `geom_smooth`. Is this what you request?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=DECA, y=TOTAL)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(se=F, method = lm, col="red") + #linear method  
  geom_smooth(se=F, col="green") # loess method
```

[image]

Comment: They are fitting a `loess` regression, not just plotting the points as they are (at least it's how it looks to me).

Comment: Hi @nicola, yes, perhaps, question is a bit unclear. Would happy to update the solution if required.

Comment: thanks you for you answer i understand my answer is not really clear for that reason i put a link when is it possible to see how i want my line to pass over the dots

Comment: I entered the `dataframe` exactly how you typed it. Can you please elaborate on why the black line is not the solution?

Comment: my column DECA in the dataframe are composed off positive and negative valor in this order :
0,10,15,-23,15,40,90,140,190,250,310,370,420
When you plot this the function automatically change the order of DECA for this :
-23,0,10,15,15,40,90,140,190,250,310,370,420
So the lines dont pass by the point in the order that i want 
i expect my explanation is more clear now